# Line by line text messaging - python & twilio

Tags: sms, twilio

I am trying to read each line from a .txt file and text-message it line by line with an enumerated number using Twilio to a phone number (using my own to test).

The below reads the file correctly, but only sends a the value of the enumerated list.

So, I receive:

> Text Message 1: 1
>
> Text Message 2: 2
>
> Text Message 3: 3

Instead of:

> Text Message 1: 1: Hello!
>
> Text Message 2: 2: This is working!
>
> Text Message 3: 3: Last Line

```
f = open("file_name")
f = list(enumerate(f, start = 1))
    for line in f:
        text = line
        print text
        client = rest.TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
        message = client.messages.create(body=text,
            to="Recipient_Number" 
            from_="Twilio_number")
        message.sid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you use `enumerate` that is creating an iterator of tuples. In your `for` loop you are only retrieving the first item in each tuple and sending that. You can use argument destructuring to get both the index and the text value, like so:

```
f = open("file_name")
f = enumerate(f, start = 1)
for index, line in f:
    text = index + ": " + line
    print text
    client = rest.TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)
    message = client.messages.create(body=text,
        to="Recipient_Number" 
        from_="Twilio_number")
    message.sid
```

Notably, you also don't need to use `list` as `enumerate` returns an iterator that can be used with `for ... in`.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks @philnash - this works well. I had to concatenate Index, ": " and line with: text = str(index) + ": " + line. and then it worked perfectly.